# Disable "new document" in document library for specific users

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, permissions, file-upload

I am trying to prevent a few users to being able to upload new documents to the document library.

How do I disable "new document" in the document library for specific users without hiding the button since other people are allowed to upload documents? Is there a way to restrict a few users access?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes,** you can restrict a few users to upload or add a new document by managing unique permission for your library as the following:

- Go to your library > Library Setting.
- Click on `Permissions for this document library`
- From the above Ribbon, > Click on `Stop the inheritance`.

[image]

- Then click to `Grant Permission` to provide a unique permission for specific

[image]

- Provide the required users and select `View Only` Permission Level

[image]

**OutPut**

There is no New document or upload document with  `View Only` Permission Level

[image]

> **Note:** You can create a group and add these users and then grant `View Only` Permission Level for this group instead
>   to do this one by one for each user.

Comment: What happen if the user is in another group that can approval? Would this specific permission gets priority? Thanks.