# How can we hide New/Upload button in modern document library experience?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-document-library

I am having 3 document libraries each one for Image, Document and Video. I know how to hide these New/Upload options in classic mode DOc libs.

Can someone suggest me what is the best way & how to achieve **Hiding** 'New' or 'Upload' button from modern experience in a doc lib

Comment: Someone Please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You have two options to hide New/Upload**

- Manage permission for this library by `breaking the inheritance` and provide the user/group `View Only` Permission Level. Check the detail steps at [Disable "new document" in document library for specific users](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/225077/disable-new-document-in-document-library-for-specific-users/225080#225080)
- Reference third-party CSS styles in SharePoint Framework Extension/ web parts

  - Unfortunately, in Modern Experience, you can't customize the page to add JS or custom CSS as we did in classic mode, meanwhile, you can [Reference third-party CSS styles in SharePoint Framework web parts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/reference-third-party-css-styles). check also

    - [SharePoint Framework Extensions Developer Preview](https://dev.office.com/blogs/announcing-availability-of-sharepoint-framework-extensions-developer-preview)
    - [Provision files (css, js) with SharePoint Framework](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226589/provision-files-css-js-with-sharepoint-framework)

Comment: @Mohammed, is there any way to get the Delete button reference from the command bar?

Comment: A ready-made solution in github https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/main/samples/js-command-hide-commands