# Hiding out of the box actions from ribbon using Spfx extensions

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, fieldcustomizers

**My requirement**:

I want the user to enter the list but I don't want him to use the out of the box actions within the lists like creating flows, quick edit, etc. I would like a user to edit the items but on a different custom page(custom list form). Now I am able to add few of my custom actions on the ribbon. When the user selects an item and clicks on one of my commands, he is redirected to a different page.

Somehow I wish to hide the out of the box actions, to restrict the default behavior of a SharePoint list (Like user creating his own flows, thus affecting designer workflows which I have created)

Attached is the image from Microsoft for reference.

Any suggestions for the same would be highly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Currently, we cannot edit the modern list view page and insert code to modify OOB options.

An idea: Insert your list to a modern page and use JavaScript/CSS via SharePoint Framework web part on the page.

[About SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/overview-client-side-web-parts)

A tool [SharePoint react script editor web part](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) as a convenience to you.

A similar case:

[How can we hide New/Upload button in modern document library experience?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/227396/how-can-we-hide-new-upload-button-in-modern-document-library-experience)