# Hide/remove shring option on a library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, json-formatting, sharing, fieldcustomizers

We have a special library where only a select few have access to. Then we learned that those select few can just share a file with anyone. Not good.

I tried creating a custom permission level, but was unsuccesful in creating one 
that hid the sharing option but maintained editing priviledges.

So I was thinking that maybe a JSON view format could work? Anyone tried that so that sharing is not visible in list view, list options and commmand bar? The user have contribute rights, so perhaps they can just create a new view and the sharing option returns?

Is a field customizer a better solution?

Hope someone can help clarify my options!

Thanks

Comment: So for the specific library, you want to users able to edit files while sharing is completely forbidden?

Comment: For only one specific library, I suggest apply a custom style sheet or JS to hide/disable Share button.

Comment: @jerry_MSFT, excactly

Comment: @MarkL, we are all modern and cannot apply a custom CSS og JS

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to the answer in another thread:

[How can we hide New/Upload button in modern document library experience?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/227396/how-can-we-hide-new-upload-button-in-modern-document-library-experience)